# Where-Object square bracket column name

Tags: powershell, square-bracket, where-object

How to filter a PowerShell object that contains a square bracket column name?

for example:

``` $data | select-object DisplayName, ``[Custom.Class`].Name ```

would return:

| DisplayName | [Custom.Class].Name |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | Animal |
| Toyota | Car |
| daisy | Plant |
| Honda | Car |

If i wanted to filter $data to list only [Custom.Class].Name = Car
How can I filter it?

I tried
``` $data | Where-Object {$_.``[Custom.Class`].Name -eq 'Car'} ```
but it returned an error
*Missing property name after reference operator.*

Tried
`$data | Where-Object {$_."[Custom.Class].Name" -eq 'Car'}`
but returned nothing

I am expecting to list only the filtered data on the column with a bracket name

Comment: the 2nd example works fine, are you sure there are no extra spaces in that property name?

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing a **bug in [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object)**, reported a while back in [GitHub issue #17068](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17068):

- In property names (possibly positionally implied `-Property` arguments) that contain [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) metacharacters meant to be interpreted *verbatim* - notably `[` and `]` - attempting to escape them with `` ` `` mistakenly causes the `` ` `` chars. to be *retained* as part of the resulting property name.

  - That is, ``` ``[Custom.Class``].Name ``` (which is the same as `` '`[Custom.Class`].Name' ``) tries to select a property named *verbatim* `` `[Custom.Class`].Name `` from the input objects, and in their absence reports `$null` values.
  - Note that the form in the question, ``` ``[Custom.Class`].Name ``` (which is the same as `` '`[Custom.Class].Name' ``) is still a wildcard expression due to the effectively *unescaped* `]`, albeit a broken one, and therefore matches none of the input properties and is simply *omitted* from the output objects.
- Incidentally, the same applies to the `-Property` and `-MemberName` parameters of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) and [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), respectively, when using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax).

As a **workaround**, replace:

```bash
... | select-object DisplayName, ``[Custom.Class``].Name
```

with:

```bash
... | select-object DisplayName, 
                    @{ Name = '[Custom.Class].Name'; 
                       Expression = { $_.'[Custom.Class].Name' } }
```

That is, use a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) to select the property whose name contains wildcard metacharacters, in which case the property names are *not* subject to interpretation as wildcard expressions.
(By contrast, `Expression = '[Custom.Class].Name'`, i.e. specifying just the property name *as a string*, would again be subject to wildcard interpretation.)

Then your 2nd attempt to query the property named `[Custom.Class].Name` verbatim will work (though you may want to use `'...'` instead of `"..."` to enclose the property name, given that string interpolation isn't needed):

```bash
$data | Where-Object { $_."[Custom.Class].Name" -eq 'Car'}
```